# Upload photos to specified photo album, on iPad

Tags: ipad, photos

Are there any ways to move photos from the default album to a specified album?

Maybe there exist some iPad apps for that? 
I know how to do that using iTunes, but you know, it's very uncomfortable :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  The iPad (as of 3.2.1) does not support the manipulation of photo albums by code running on an iPad through any approved mechanism.